# Android Studio - change background image size

Tags: android, image, background

So, i wanted to put an image in background of my screen. My problem is that if i just add the image to "background" it will fill all the screen, and my image gets defaced. I could put as an ImageView, but the problem is that i have an expandableListView in the same screen, and i wanted the image to stay behind, as a background. 
Any idea how to do this? 
Can have 2 solutions: Put as an imagemView but behind the list. Or add as a background but resize it. How can i do it?

Here is what happened:

[image]

He is what happens if i put the image as an imageView:

[image]

Comment: A background is automatically stretched to fill the view.  If you don't want that, you need to use something that gives you more control, like an ImageView where you can set the scale type.

Comment: if you dont want to use an `ImageView` behind the `ListView` create a custom `Drawable` class and use it with `listView.setBackground(Drawable)`

Comment: @GabeSechan 
But if i use an imageView i create another problem. The image will stay in front of my expandableListView. See the example i put on top

Comment: did you use a `FrameLayout`?

Comment: You can have the image behind, just depends on your layout. For example if in a relative layout, the order in the file controls the z order. Same with frame layouts

Comment: Another solution would be what @pskink suggested and create a drawable class that doesn't stretch the image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this is very easy to achieve with relative layouts

```
<RelativeLayout ... > 
    <ImageView ... 
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop“ /> 
    <ListView ... 
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true“ /> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

With a relative layout z-index is decided by the order you declare the tags, so stuff towards the bottom of the xml is in front of stuff from closer to the top, when they are in the same position.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about the order.. :b

Answer (score 0):

Use a FrameLayout  (Inside FrameLayout view written on top will appear on top and so on)

```
<FrameLayout
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    ></ListView>


<ImageView
    android:layout_width="your_width_in_dp"
    android:layout_height="your_height_in_dp"
    />

</FrameLayout>
```

You can also place FrameLayout inside another layout.